# How to clear .NET interactive cell output programmatically

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, dotnet-interactive

When a cell that contains referencing statements such as `#r "nuget: FSharp.Data, 4.1.1"` the cell automatically prints to output something like the following

```
Installed Packages
- Deedle, 2.3.0
- fsharp.core, 5.0.0
- ...
```

Which can be very long depending on how many dependencies each referenced package has.

Is there a way to clear the cell output? Something like `Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Notebook.CurrentCell.ClearOutput()`

A solution where we can silence these messages would also be helpful.